# Problem changing to a new timer with self-installed ground wire in old NYC building

Tags: hvac, ground

I am trying to change my Lutron timer to a new timer (which needs to be grounded). My home is a NYC condo built in 1950s - so I *guess* I have AC cables. I did not see any ground wire inside the metal box, so I went to home depot to get a ground wire pigtail and screwed it to the back of the box (see picture). I tested there is current passing through the hot and the ground (see picture - the circuit tester lit up). And of course, I also tested there is current passing through the hot and the load.

However, the new timer still doesn't work. What could go wrong? How to fix? If you need more info, let me know. Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The bare wires showing on the wire nut might give a problem in the future, should try to not show any bare wire on your connections.  You probably have metal conduit which is/acts as your ground, the bought ground pigtail probably not needed, just attach switch ground to box.

Comment: Yes, I'll use electric tape to wrap the nut so no exposed bare wires

Comment: Twist the nut on much more firmly, or go buy a Wago connector instead. Wire nuts that have to be taped tend to fall off later. Something other than hilarity ensues.

Comment: What model of timer are you using, and can you post some photos that show clearly where the wires enter the box please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in NYC, you most likely have individual wires in conduit, and conduit was metal then.  Or indeed possibly AC cables.

Cut power and do a diagnostic. Get a receptacle and wire it up with brass screw to an always-hot supply wire and silver screw to that ground pigtail.  Plug a night-light into it (switched on).  Power back up. Does the night-light light?  That validates the ground.  (at least as far as goes a powered switch that has been UL Listed to use ground).

I gather you are using an electronic pushbutton timer switch that does not require neutral (but requires ground as a substitute for neutral, in a manner UL approved).  *You know, they make clockwork timer switches that don't require neutral or ground*. They are powered by the user!

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I took out the ground pigtail, remove the plastic piece attached to the screw on the yoke (using this as the ground instead of the pigtail), and installed the timer again. This time the timer works.

I still don't know why the ground pigtail method doesn't work though.